# how to resolve " can not resolve method 'findOne (com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)' " error for mongodb in intellij ide which is very new to me

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea

```
post = postsCollection.findOne(new BasicDBObject("permalink",  
  permalink));
```

can not resolve method

```
'findOne (com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)',
                         'update  (com.mongodb.BasicDBObject,boolean,boolean),
```

findone,update are 
  showing error in my intellij ide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which namespace findOne,update methods are present in java driver while connecting to mongodb plz  tell me ..........

Answer (score 0):

findOne and update are found in class DBCollection.You can use them by

```
"import com.mongodb.DBCollection;"
```

Also refer http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html